# How to stop Entity Framework from filling entities automatically?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

Consider the following code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Initialize the ObjectContext

            storeContext = new storeEntities();                               

          gridControl.DataSource = storeContext.Products;

     }
```

When Form1 is loaded the gridControl is already filled with a list of Products even without me explicitly filling the products list . When using datasets , the tables have  to be loaded explicitly (by calling a fill or get method) which makes sense.

My questions are

1 - If this is the default behavior does it mean that the other entities in the object context that I am not accessing are being filled automatically as well ?

2 - If yes can I override this behavior ? How ?

Thanks in advance,

Wrath

Answer (score 1):

> When Form1 is loaded the gridControl is already filled with a list of Products even without me explicitly filling the products list.

You're binding the grid control's data source to the `Products` table. In other words, you're asking the grid control to look at the contents of `storeContext.Products` - and that will retrieve the data.

> If this is the default behavior does it mean that the other entities in the object context that I am not accessing are being filled automatically as well?

No, only the ones that you've asked for. See Øyvind's answer for details of entities related to ones you're already loading though.

> If yes can I override this behavior? How?

Just don't set the data source of the grid control to `storeContext.Products`. If you want to fetch the data later, then do the binding later. You *could* bind to an empty list and explicitly populate it later on, if you wanted.

Comment: So to be clear , Entity Framework queries the database and fills an entity when I access that entity in the objectContext (say storeContext.Products)? If I never access a given entity it will never be filled in the background.

Comment: @Wrath: Just fetching the `storeContext.Products` property won't issue the query - but *iterating* over the data in that (as binding will do) will fetch the data. And yes, if you don't access anything, it won't be fetched.

Comment: You have been of great help. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Lazy Loading is default setting for Entity Framework, meaning that the properties that link to other tables will not be filled in automatically, but will be fetched from the database when they are needed/accessed by your code. So for example serializing an object will fetch all related data since the serializer moves through all the properties on the object to save them in some serialized state.

To stop this, you can turn of lazy loading on the context like this:

```
objectContext.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

This will cause the related properties to need explicit loading by you before they get their proper value, often done by using the `Include` keyword while writing the query itself to indicate which of the related data you want to fetch while also fetching the main data.